# String insert method not working for non-zero Index

Tags: java

I receive an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for the following code, even though the string is 10 characters long. The error occurs on the third last line of code `printedLine.insert(3, '-');`.

```
public class Program1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int caseNumber, numberOfCases;
        String currentLine;
        int lineNumber;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        numberOfCases = in.nextInt();
        String[] phoneNumbers = new String[numberOfCases + 1];

        for (caseNumber = 0; caseNumber <= numberOfCases; caseNumber++) {
            phoneNumbers[caseNumber] = in.nextLine();
        }

        for (lineNumber = 0; lineNumber < phoneNumbers.length; lineNumber++) {
            currentLine = phoneNumbers[lineNumber];
            currentLine = currentLine.replaceAll("-", "");

            if (currentLine.length() > 10) {
                currentLine = currentLine.substring(0, 10);
            }

            System.out.println(currentLine);

            StringBuffer printedLine = new StringBuffer(currentLine);
            printedLine.insert(3, '-');
            printedLine.insert(7, '-');

            System.out.println(printedLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this is the case?

UPDATE: If I just print the String Buffer object, all the values line up with the original string, which is 10 characters long.

Comment: Could you give us the output of `currentLine` please. Also, `printedLine` is a StringBuffer object, not a `String` as your question seems to indicate you think.

Comment: `currentLine` must have been less than 4 characters long.

Comment: Add a `in.nextLine();` after the `in.nextInt()` to consume the `"\n"`.

Comment: Print out all values with a `System.out.println(someVariable);`and see if they match up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first element is "" in phoneNumbers i.e. phoneNumbers[0] is empty string. So its string length is 0 and so you cannot do this insert.

Here is your program fixed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int caseNumber, numberOfCases;
        String currentLine;
        int lineNumber;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        numberOfCases = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        String[] phoneNumbers = new String[numberOfCases];

        for (caseNumber = 0; caseNumber < numberOfCases; caseNumber++) {
            phoneNumbers[caseNumber] = in.nextLine();
        }

        for (lineNumber = 0; lineNumber < phoneNumbers.length; lineNumber++) {
            currentLine = phoneNumbers[lineNumber];
            currentLine = currentLine.replaceAll("-", "");

            if (currentLine.length() > 10) {
                currentLine = currentLine.substring(0, 10);
            }

            System.out.println(currentLine);

            StringBuffer printedLine = new StringBuffer(currentLine);
            printedLine.insert(3, '-');
            printedLine.insert(7, '-');

            System.out.println(printedLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using `in.nextInt();` when trying to consume more tokens is that it only reads the int value.

The moment you press  <kbd>Enter</kbd>  to insert another value and try to use  `in.nextLine();` it will consume the `"\n"` that the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key "typed" and not the value you just entered!

There are two solutions to this kind of problem:

```
numberOfCases = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine(); // (It consumes the \n character)
```

Or

```
numberOfCases = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

Comment: +1 for explaining what is the real cause of the issue.